# jQuery select p inside this

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I am having some trouble with selecting a p tag inside of the clicked ID, code is as follows;

> ```
> <tbody>
>     <tr id="test1">
>     <p>
>         Some random text that should show up in the dialog.
>     </p>
>         <td>test</td>
>         <td>test</td>
>     </tr>
>     ... the rest of the tr's are identical, nothing else to see here.
>  </tbody>
>
>
> $('#test1, #test2, #test3, #test4').click(function(){
>     $(this 'p').dialog();
> });
> ```

Test it live; http://team-blandsaft.no-ip.org/

Better get used to writing some code in the stackoverflow editor.

Comment: Off topic: tr elements should only have td children. Also $(this 'p') isn't even syntactically correct

Comment: If you put that HTML in a page, the `p` will be moved (since it's not a valid child of a `tr`) elsewhere when the DOM is being constructed: [demonstration JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UQ2NL/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(this).find('p').dialog();
```

or you can use the [context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context)

```
$('p',this).dialog();
```

which internally uses the find method

As others have mentioned you have invalid html with `<p>` as a children of `<tr>`

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/tr) for tr

> Permitted content: Zero or more `<td>` or `<th>` elements, or a mix of them

Comment: And it *still* won't work, since the `p` will be moved outside of the `table` element, when the DOM is constructed, *because it's invalid html*: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UQ2NL/).

Comment: @initium, isn't the syntax to open a jquery UI dialog `.dialog('open')`?

Comment: @initium You're going to have to pull those `p` elements out of your `table` since it's invalid HTML (or put them in a `td`). If you pull them out of your table, you can give all of them a class, and then select on that class to activate your dialogs: `$('.dialog-class').dialog();`. That way you are not dependent on your `table` for selecting what elements get turned into a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test1, #test2, #test3, #test4').click(function(){
    $(this).children('p').dialog();
});
```